# How to prevent opening details when clicking on mat-label?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

I have multiple details elements. When clicking on mat-label, details is opening, whether $event.stopPropagation() is used or not. I would like to prevent that behaviour because the user expects to focus the input instead of opening the details.

```
<details>
  <summary>
    <mat-form-field (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
      <mat-label (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">First Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput value="Marvel" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </summary>
  details
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I came up with this solution and it is working.

```
<details (click)="handleDetailsClick($event)">
  <summary>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput value="Marvel" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </summary>
  details
</details>

handleDetailsClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((event.target as Element).classList.contains('mat-form-field-infix')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**